# Vaadin Spring Navbar

Tags: html, spring, vaadin

I am trying to add a navbar (just like bootstrap's) for a Spring application but am not getting the nav menu to appear on the web page!

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here?

Below is my code:

```
private Panel viewContainer;

private HorizontalLayout navbar;

private Button btnHome;
private Button btnNested;

private Button createNavigationButton(String caption, final String viewName) {
    Button button = new Button(caption);
    button.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_SMALL);
    // If you didn't choose Java 8 when creating the project, convert this
    // to an anonymous listener class
    button.addClickListener(event -> getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(
            viewName));
    return button;
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
    root.setSizeFull();

    navbar = new HorizontalLayout();
    navbar.setWidth("100%");
    navbar.setDefaultComponentAlignment(Alignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT);
    root.addComponent(navbar);

    final Label brand = new Label("Nested demo");
    brand.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H1);
    brand.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_NO_MARGIN);
    navbar.addComponent(brand);
    navbar.setComponentAlignment(brand, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);
    navbar.setExpandRatio(brand, 1);

    btnHome = new Button("Home", FontAwesome.HOME);
    btnHome.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_BORDERLESS);

    navbar.addComponent(btnHome);

    btnNested = new Button("nested", FontAwesome.COFFEE);
    btnNested.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_BORDERLESS);

    navbar.addComponent(btnNested);

    viewContainer = new Panel();
    viewContainer.setSizeFull();
    root.addComponent(viewContainer);
    root.setExpandRatio(viewContainer, 1);
    }
```

Any hint is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is _only_ the navbar missing? are there any hints of it beeing there (e.g. what do your browsers' devtools tell you)?

Comment: Seems that setContent(root); call is missing from the init method.

Answer (score 0):

Henri's comment is almost certainly the correct answer.

Judging by the init(VaadinRequest) code you're using a UI class.

Without `setContent(some components with visible stuff in them);` 
you won't see anything.

'you won't see anything' happens a lot in Vaadin when you're attempting new things, or doing proof of concept stuff.  IMHO it's always a good practice to start with really dumb UI stuff e.g. setContent(new Label("TODO - implement this content-xxx"));

Using browser dev-tools is also a great idea.  A quick select-element should show you that the UI div is empty, and allow you to start diagnosing.

**TL;DR :-**

UI is a ComponentContainer, so you need to - either

```
setContent(myLayoutWithStuff);
```

or

```
getContent().addComponent(myStuff);
```

to show someStuff.